# Can I send a form using <h3> tag using js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to send a form without using button. I want to send it when the user clicks on the text so can I do it using JS or not. this is my code

```
 function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        //document.updateForm.qty.value=xmlHttp.responseText;
        var val = xmlHttp.responseText;
        var res = val.split("#");
        var html="<table>";
        for(var i=0; i<res.length-1 ; i++ ){
            //document.getElementById('results').innerHTML  +="<tr><td> <a href='www.google.com'>" + res[i] + '</a></td></tr>';
       // html+="<tr><td></form> <a href = "+ 'changeRoles.php?un=' + res[i] + '>'+ res[i]   + "</td></tr>";
            html+= "<tr><td><form name = 'choose' method='post'> <h3 onclick='document.choose.submit();'>"+res[i]+"</h3> <input type='hidden' name = 'un' value = '"+ res[i]+"'>  </form></td></tr>";
        }
html+="</table>";
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, it is possible. Just add the target url to the form element's `action` attribute.

But why would you want to break user expectations and best practices for UI design ?

```html
<table>
    <thead/>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="<your url goes here>" name='choose' method='post'>
                    <h3 onclick='document.choose.submit();'>Whatsup</h3>
                    <input type='hidden' name = 'un' value = 'blarf'>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the problem is when I  click on the text nothing happens

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Have you added an `action` attribute with a proper url to the form element? Does the server behind the url process the request correctly (or is it capable of doing so in the first place)? Have you inspected the http traffic with a web proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)  (no affiliation) ?

Comment: the text is not clickable and yes I have added the action.

Comment: Well, the text _is_ clickable in the demo above (on Chrome anyway), as you can verify by  its disapparition upon  a mouse click. If you cannot reproduce this behavior please specify the browser or provide more details in which context you are using the solution. Foremost show the html into which you integrate the form.

Answer (score 0):

First define a callback method

call the defined method from <h3> tag

Example is given below.

**Try and let me know whether you have any further query**

```
function action1()
{
$.ajax({
  url : 'example.com',
  type: 'GET',
  success : handleData
});
}

<h3 onclick='action1();'>Submit</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will run. Just copy paste once. Check it. Then let me know if you have any other query.

```js
function action1()
   {
    $.ajax({
         url: 'some_unknown_page.html',
         success: function (response) {
             alert("I am success");
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
             alert("I am clickable");
        
         },
    });
   }
```

```html
<html>
<header>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
  
  <form name = 'choose' action="asdada" method='post'> 
   <h3 onclick='action1();'>Click Me</h3>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```